# Why sudo apt install /path/*.deb produces permisson denied whereas sudo dpkg -i /path/*.deb works fine?

Tags: apt, sudo, dpkg, acl

I was wondering for a long time why `sudo apt` fails to install local `deb` from some folders with error:

```
Failed to fetch a file... Permission denied
```

Recently I've tried `sudo dpkg -i` same path and it worked. The path is on USB mounted with `udisks`, so it is inside a `/media/user` folder and as of now my guess it is due to `ACL` on that folder (`drwxr-x---+`). But why a command with `sudo` gets permission denied? Why then other command on same files works fine?

I would use `dpkg` but it does not process pre-dependencies in proper order as opposed to `apt`.

Is there any way to skip fetching part for `apt`? Before fetching, near start of output `apt` gives `Note selecting abc instead of abc.20-2-a.deb`. Is there a way to make `apt` process particular `deb` files, not to try to locate others?

P.S. I'm aware of other ways to install local debs, e.g. adding local repository or using non-preinstalled `apt-offline` from [How to install packages without internet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313690/how-to-install-packages-without-internet) , but I'd like to keep things simple (plus I suspect local repository way could face same permission denied issue).

Added 2:

```
sudo mount rd -t tmpfs /media/mint/rd -o x-mount.mkdir
sudo mount ram -t tmpfs /media/ram -o x-mount.mkdir
```

apt from `rd` fails, apt from `ram` works fine, so I guess the problem is in `mint` ACL, I've tried to show it below, I do not understand ACL on Linux much. Inserted USB drives are mounted under user's `mint` (liveUSB user), so I want to tackle it. When I `sudo -i` and get root command prompt then I could manually `mkdir`, `mv` withing `rd`, also `sudo touch /media/mint/rd/mpv/1` created a file, so why `sudo apt` fails?

Added:

permissions inc. ACL:

```
mint@mint:~$ ls -la /media/mint/rd
total 0
drwxrwxrwt  4 root root 80 Oct 24 03:23 .
drwxr-xrw-+ 4 root root 80 Oct 24 03:22 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 mint mint 80 Oct 12 23:01 ffmpeg
drwxrwxrwx  2 mint mint 60 Oct 11 17:53 mpv

ACL:
mint@mint:~$ getfacl /media/mint/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/mint/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:mint:r-x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::rw-
```

apt / apt-get output:

```
mint@mint:~$ sudo apt install -d /media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/*.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'ffmpeg' instead of '/media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_7%3a4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb'
Note, selecting 'libavresample4' instead of '/media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/libavresample4_7%3a4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb'
Suggested packages:
  ffmpeg-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ffmpeg libavresample4
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 71 not upgraded.
Need to get 1507 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2275 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavresample4 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 ffmpeg amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavresample4 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 ffmpeg amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavresample4 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 [54.2 kB]
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavresample4 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  File not found - /media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/libavresample4_70x0.07ffe00000006p-10224.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb (13: Permission denied)
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 ffmpeg amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 [1453 kB]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 ffmpeg amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  File not found - /media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_70x0.07ffe00000002p-10224.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch file:/media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/libavresample4_7%3a4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  File not found - /media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/libavresample4_70x0.07ffe00000006p-10224.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch file:/media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_7%3a4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  File not found - /media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_70x0.07ffe00000002p-10224.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb (13: Permission denied)
E: Some files failed to download
mint@mint:~$ sudo apt-get install -d /media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/*.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'ffmpeg' instead of '/media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_7%3a4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb'
Note, selecting 'libavresample4' instead of '/media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/libavresample4_7%3a4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb'
Suggested packages:
  ffmpeg-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ffmpeg libavresample4
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 71 not upgraded.
Need to get 1507 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2275 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavresample4 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 ffmpeg amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavresample4 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 ffmpeg amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavresample4 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 [54.2 kB]
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavresample4 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  File not found - /media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/libavresample4_70x0.07fff00000006p-10224.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb (13: Permission denied)
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 ffmpeg amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 [1453 kB]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 ffmpeg amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  File not found - /media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_70x0.07fff00000002p-10224.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch file:/media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/libavresample4_7%3a4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  File not found - /media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/libavresample4_70x0.07fff00000006p-10224.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch file:/media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_7%3a4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  File not found - /media/mint/rd/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_70x0.07fff00000002p-10224.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb (13: Permission denied)
E: Some files failed to download
```

Answer (score 3):

As I've understood now (thanks to the comments) `sudo apt` uses `_apt` user. And absence of execute permission for parent folder `/media/mint` prevented it from accessing the files. The workaround is to add exec permission, e.g.

```
setfacl -m u:_apt:x /media/mint
```